# Horizontal Nav Bar with logos

Tags: css, navbar

I am struggling with the following, could you please help?

I want the logos to be aligned next to each other to the left and the links aligned next to each other to the :

[Logo1] [Logo2] [Logo3] (spaceeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee) [Link1] [Link2] [Link3]

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 8%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav .logo {
  width: 40px;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="images/Logo1.svg" class="logo">
  <img src="images/Logo2.svg" class="logo">
  <img src="images/Logo3.svg" class="logo">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I tried changing attributes under nav .logo but was not successfull (e.g. dispay and position)

Answer (score 1):

I think the code snippet I have attached below should work. I did change your code up a bit (changes not related to the solution) to include a placeholder image and make the link colors black so you could see how everything looks.

First, I grouped your logos and your links into two separate divs. Since your `nav` has the properties `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`, it was causing all of your elements in `nav` to be evenly distributed in the line. By grouping the logos and links into two separate divs,  the property evenly distributed the two groups instead of every element.

Next, I changed your `margin-left` property in `nav ul li` from `40px` to `10px`. This change helps make the spacing between your links much smaller. To simulate the same spacing for your logos, I added the property `margin-right: 10px` to the `nav .logo` selector. Hopefully this helps!

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 8%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav .logo {
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logos">
    <img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/300/DEDEDE/555555/Logo%201" class="logo">
    <img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/300/DEDEDE/555555/Logo%202" class="logo">
    <img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/300/DEDEDE/555555/Logo%203" class="logo">
  </div>

  <div class="links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 
You define a class "logos" (different from the "logo" in each img) in the first div but you don't describe it in the css. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Technically, you could remove the class declarations from both divs I've added. In this case, the class declarations are unnecessary, I just added them so it would be easier to understand the code. The important thing is actually adding the new divs themselves, as they are what group your logos and links to make the formatting work. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
  max-width: 1220px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: rgba(101, 67, 33, 0.5);
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

.menu__links-list{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 0px 20px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.menu__link a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="menu">
    <div class="menu__logos">
      <img class="menu__logo" src="http://dummyimage.com/40" alt="">
      <img class="menu__logo" src="http://dummyimage.com/40" alt="">
      <img class="menu__logo" src="http://dummyimage.com/40" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="menu__links">
      <ul class="menu__links-list">
        <li class="menu__link"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li class="menu__link"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li class="menu__link"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).